# Failed to export Firebase.Crashlytics crash report by BigQuery

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, crashlytics

I try to export my Android app crash report as some formatted text file. I changed payment plan to Blaze.
In my Firebase.Crashlytics web page, I saw some crash reports.
I try to setup BigQuery export. But I see "Dataset not created". Do I missing some setup?

I try to run this SQL on BigQuery console.

> SELECT * FROM `projectId.firebase_crashlytics.package_name_ANDROID`

I got projectId like "myapp-99c49", is that correct format?
firebase_crashlytics part is not sure. Should I change?
package_name_ANDROID is like "com.example.myapp" is correct format?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example you need something like:

```
myapp-99c49.firebase_crashlytics.com_example_myapp_ANDROID
```